# Is it possible to keep onions in a room and avoid odors?

Tags: storage-method, onions, smell, kitchen

There is a kitchen without a porch or cabinet handy to store onions. How can I store onions in a way that doesn't cause odors in the kitchen? Is it even possible?

Comment: Unless they're rotten, or you start slicing them, I've never noticed any real odours from the 5-10 onions I have sitting on a shelf all year long...

Comment: @DanMašek: When I buy onions they already have a smell. It is not bad but it is the regular smell of onions. My concern is that since I don't have a dedicated storage or porch the whole room will smell of onions. Is there any trick to avoid that? I think placing them in a bag will just spoil them

Comment: Yup - they only smell when damaged. Rot, bruising or cutting will do that. An onion in good condition doesn't stink.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: They don't stink but they do have a distinct odor right? That's what I am talking about

Comment: @Jim they really don’t. Whole onions with the husks still on should smell like nothing, unless your nose gets *really really close*.

Comment: …though, just to keep terminology straight, I would not say that about the green stalks of *spring onions*, aka *green onions* (aka scallions).

Comment: … which could also be explained by how easily they bruise @Sneftel. They don’t smell if untouched in a garden bed.

Comment: Jim, sounds like the onions you are buying are already old.

Comment: Or (@FuzzyChef) Jim has a sensitive nose and is noticing the smell opening a closed bag of them.  It's subtle, but it's there. I keep mine in a cardboard box in a cool cupboard.  Good onions smell different to bad ones as well as much less, but if I open the box near my face and there are several in there I can smell them. Once diluted in room air, it's not noticeable at all.

Comment: @ChrisH: Do you have holes in the cardboard box?

Comment: @Jim no, but neither is it sealed in any way

Comment: @FuzzyChef: So when you go to the groceries store in the area of the onions are you saying you don't smell anything even there due to freshness?

Comment: Oh, you can smell a little.  But it's not going to fill the kitchen.  I put my onions in a basket in the pantry, and the pantry doesn't smell of onions unless one of them goes bad.

Comment: ‘How can I store onions in a way that doesn't cause odors in the kitchen? Is it even possible?‘ If you’re hypersensitive to linoleic acid, nope. Otherwise this ought n’t to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To store onions so that their smell does not invade the entire refrigerator, there is nothing better than storing them in airtight containers. It is vital to put absorbent paper as a base.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming papery peel left on. Hard to control scent wafting with moisture evaporating from peeled onions.

Bury in flour covering by 2 inches or so.
Keep cool.

Originally in Bavaria, rootveg was protected from rot/ sprouting by burying in sand in cellar

Flour will be contamiated with any mold dust etc but altered scent only after very prolonged use.

Comment: Is this something you personally do?

Comment: how do you use the flour later, doesn't it absorb some of the smell / flavor (or even moisture)? Or do you have to toss it after a while? Can you [edit] your answer to provide more details?

Comment: Storing root vegetables in _slightly damp_ sand is common tradition _but not for onions_, which are stored dry, sometimes even braided and hung up. I don’t see how the paragraph about root vegetables fits in logically?

Comment: It really seems like you're going to end up with damp, moldy, weevil-ridden flour within a week or two.